# How to change Xcode template to use @import Foundation; instead of #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Tags: xcode, templates

Is there anyway to convince Xcode to use `@import Foundation;` or `@import UIKit;` when creating new files?

I noticed that the template files use a variable called `___IMPORTHEADER_cocoaSubclass___`, but I have not found anyway to stitch into this.

There is a file in Xcode.app at...

`/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Base/Base_DefinitionsLanguage.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist`

...that contains the key: `*:imports:importFramework:*` that was set to

`#import <___*___/___*___.h>`

I switched it to

`@import ___*___;`

but that didn't seem to have any effect.